# Jquery datatable on row click brings the old data in a pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, datatables

I have a scenario where I bind my data in a `Jquery datatable`. So for that I did something like this.

```js
function getDashboardData() {    

    var ddlState = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlR4GState').val();

    try {

        $('#grdMWSiteSurvey_wrapper').show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/BindMWSiteSurvey",
            data: JSON.stringify({ STATE: ddlState }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var datVal = JSON.parse(data.d);

                if (ddlState == "Select State") {
                    hideLoader();
                    $('#grdMWSiteSurvey_wrapper').hide();
                    return false;
                }

                else {

                    if (datVal.length == 0) {
                        hideLoader();
                        $('#grdMWSiteSurvey_wrapper').hide();
                        return false;
                    }

                    var details = [];

                    var result = "";
                    for (var i = 0, len = datVal.length; i < len; i++) {                        
                        result = datVal[i];

                        var buttonColumn = "<b><button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onClick=" + 'OpenPopUpForUpdate("' + result.STATECODE + '");' + ">Edit</span></button></b>";
                        details.push([result.SAP_ID, result.CANDIDATE_ID, result.STATE, result.SITE_NAME, result.CANDIDATESTATUS, buttonColumn]);
                    }


                    $('#grdMWSiteSurvey').DataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        autoWidth: false,
                        "aaData": details,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "Sap ID" },
                            { "sTitle": "Candidate ID" },
                            { "sTitle": "State" },
                            { "sTitle": "Site Name" },
                            { "sTitle": "Candidate Status" },
                            //{ "sTitle": "Current Status" },
                            { "sTitle": "ACTION" }
                        ],                        
                        "bDestroy": true
                        //"bServerSide": true
                    });

                    hideLoader();
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                hideLoader();
                alert('Cannot load the data currently, Please try after sometime..!!');
            }
        });

    } catch (e) {
        //exception
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="grdMWSiteSurvey" class="display responsive nowrap"></table>
```

So when the above code is ran, it shows and binds the data something like below.

[image: datatable grid]

What I am stuck with is

> Whenever I click on the Edit button of the grid say for the first time, the data comes in a pop up of the proper relevant row. But when I click for the third fourth time, it shows me the data of the earlier rows. Why does that happens.

Below is the code for getting the data in a pop up

```js
// Open popup for edit
function OpenPopUpForUpdate(StateCode) {

    var table = $('#grdMWSiteSurvey').DataTable();
    stateCode = StateCode;

    $('#grdMWSiteSurvey tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var row = table.row(this).data();

        GetIframeSRC(row[0], row[1], row[2], stateCode, row[6], row[7]);
    });
}

// set iframe
function GetIframeSRC(SapID, CandidateID, state, stateCode) {

    //  showLoader();

    var Iframesrc = "FileUpload.aspx?SapID=" + SapID + "&CandID=" + CandidateID + "&St=" + state + "&Stcod=" + stateCode + "&UName=" + LoginUsername;

    $("#ifrmDownload").attr({
        'src': Iframesrc
    });

    // hideLoader();
}
```

So what is the error and root cause of this. Please suggest.

**NOTE** I took the reference of datatable from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "But when I click for the third fourth time, it shows me the data of the earlier rows"? What happens when you click the second time?

Comment: @edkeveked: when I click for the second time on edit button I get that row data in a pop up. Similarly when I click that edit button for third fourth time on other edit button I get old data.

Comment: @edkeveked: I m here online now... let me know if you come

Comment: After editing your row, do you have a button on which you press to confirm that you have finished editing?

Comment: @edkeveked: I have that Inside the `iframe` let me know that.. so that I can post that html too.

Comment: You edit your row in the iframe. Do you have a button on the iframe? if yes, which function does the button call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170058/discussion-between-bnn-and-edkeveked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and studying the documents from the datatables with my colleague, I came up with a solution which is clear cut and working fine for me.

First what I did is, I removed the `onClick=" + 'OpenPopUpForUpdate("' + result.STATECODE + '");' + "` function from the variable of `button`

Then I added the bootstrap properties like below. Some sample link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

```
var buttonColumn = "<b><button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-candidateid='" + result.CANDIDATE_ID + "' data-sapid='" + result.SAP_ID + "' data-statecode='" + result.STATECODE + "' data-state='" + result.STATE + "' data-target='#myModal'>Edit</span></button></b>";
```

Then on document load, I write `onClick` property. Like below

```
$(document).on('click', 'table#grdMWSiteSurvey button[data-target="#myModal"]', function () {   
GetIframeSRC($(this).data('sapid'), $(this).data('candidateid'), $(this).data('state'), $(this).data('statecode'), LoginUsername);   });
```

And binded the `GetIframeSRC` like below

```
function GetIframeSRC(SapID, CandidateID, state, stateCode) {

//  showLoader();
var Iframesrc = "FileUpload.aspx?SapID=" + SapID + "&CandID=" + CandidateID + "&St=" + state + "&Stcod=" + stateCode + "&UName=" + LoginUsername;

$("#ifrmDownload").attr({
    'src': Iframesrc
});
// hideLoader();
```

}

That's what all I needed. Cheers to everyone who supported  me

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue with the code is that you are not saving the data after editing your row.

After editing your row, you wil have to save the data. Let's suppose you have a button in your iframe that you will press after editing and that the button will call a function `saveData()`

```
function OpenPopUpForUpdate(StateCode) {

    var table = $('#grdMWSiteSurvey').DataTable();
    stateCode = StateCode;

    $('#grdMWSiteSurvey tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var row = table.row(this).data();
        var that = this; // save the row that is selected 

        GetIframeSRC(row[0], row[1], row[2], stateCode, row[6], row[7]);
    });
}

function saveData() {
 // use jquery to get the data you have just edited and save it in a variable "newData"
 table
        .row( that ) // change the selected row in the datatable
        .data( newData ) // with the newData
        .draw();
}
```

Comment: what If I dont want to save data. just close the pop up and click on other edit button

Comment: hi, I have posted the answer. do check and let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: did u understand what I did in my above answer ?